# Get highest en lowest value from attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, products

On the category page I have an attribute showing values, that attribute can have multiple values and will show all the values separated by commas. Is there a way to get the highest value from the attribute and also the lowest?

What is have to display the values:

```
<?php if ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('scherm_breedte')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)): ?>
    <strong>Breedte</strong>: <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('scherm_breedte')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Which type does the attribute have?

Comment: which type of values it have like integer or something else can please show example of your values

Comment: The type is: Multiple selection and the input will be numbers like: 150 160 200 210 250 300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically its not a Magento question rather a PHP question.

Try like this

```
$attribtesData = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('scherm_breedte')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    $attributeDataArray = explode(",",$attribtesData);

    echo 'Max attribute Value = '.max($attributeDataArray);
    echo 'Min attribute Value = '.min($attributeDataArray);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Welcome back buddy :-)

Comment: @BabyinMagento Thanks :) Ready to rocks again.